# What does 'X min read' mean on Medium?

Tags: medium

What does "2 min read", "1 min read" mean on [Medium](https://medium.com/)?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"An estimate of how long it will take you to read that story (in minutes)."

[image]

Source: [Read Time - Medium](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214991667-Read-time)